# How to eager load relations right after creation in Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

I am using php slim3 fraemwork and eloquent orm in my app.
And I have puzzled with eloquent relations loading..

I would like to populate my object with relations on creation

Let's say I have a Company and User models
User has `company` method and Company has `users` method as well.
Both methods described properly

```
//User.php
company() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Company');
}

//Company.php
users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('User');
}
```

Than somewhere I want to create a new company with users

```
function doSomething(array $data)
{
    $company= new Company();
    //fill it
    //...
    $users = [];
    foreach ($data['user_emails'] as $email)
    {
        $users[] = new User(['email' => $email]);
    }
    $company->users()->saveMany($users);
    $company->save();

    return $company();
}


$company = doSomething(['emails'] => ['foo@mail.com', 'buz@mail.com']);

//rely on build in to Model toString that uses json serialization
echo $company;
```

In this example company and relations will be saved - it works
But in company json will be company only
And I would like to see it with users as well

In case I have this company already I can use `with`

```
echo Company::query()->with('user')->get();
```

But I alreay have all data I need - no needs to re-fetch it from db again.
Do there is a way to return Company with related users right after creation?

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is really old, but I stumbled upon this when searching something similar...

I think the best way is to use lazy eager loading, with [**load()**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) or [**loadMissing()**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) (if you want to load only if they aren't already loaded).

So, in your example, you could do:

```
return $company->load('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a tricky way
Initiated relations manually right before return it from `doSomething` method..

```
$company->setRelation('users', new Collection($users));
```

Looks unobvious and tricky

Please advice if there are any other way to reach my case?